# React - Reuse a form component and show it under comments based on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a working react component `<CommentForm/>` that is shown at the bottom of a list of comments.

I have a reply button under each comment that when clicked needs to show the same `<CommentForm/>` under the reply button. One instance of `<CommentForm/>`  is always rendered under the list of comments. The comments are coming from a database.

Here is my code for the reply button:

```
  <Button size="small" variant="outlined" onClick={(event) => replyToComment(event)}>Reply</Button>
```

I tried this but I dont think that works in React?

```
const replyToComment = async (event) => {

  return <CommentForm/>;
}
```

If I add this component under the button and show it based on state, it shows under all the reply buttons.

```
<CommentForm show={someStateField}/>
```

Is this feasible or is showing a popup dialog with reply form the only option?

[image]